# How to calculate a value for each key of a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, accumulator

Is there any way to set the accumulator to 0 after every time we use it and after that it still performs the same function? or How to calculate the overall value for each key in a Map like this :  String, Hashmap String, Integer  ? I am trying to be as clarifying as I can but I don't have a clue about that.

```
/*EXAMPLE OF HASHMAP:  String e.g - UK ; America ; Africa , etc. String e.g - black , white, asian Integer e.g- 2008 , 103432 , 2391 // for every country the values are diff
*/
//one way to think of this is maybe with accumulator
// THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CODE WHICH DOES NOTHING.
int acc = 0 ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ ) {
if ( i == 1 ) {
acc++;  }       // after acc ++  and it is 1, I want it to be again 0;
if ( i == 3 ) {
acc++;  }       // so that on this stage it will be 1
}

//Another alternative way may be:
Map<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> question = new HashMap<>();
int count = 0 ;
for(String regions : question.keySet())
{
for (String people : question.get(regions).keySet())
{
count = count + question.get(regions).get(people);  // and here it will count all the value but I want to count it for each region and then become to 0 again, so that I can have the overall value for each of the people(keys)
}
}
```

Comment: ...not getting what you mean. You can just `acc = 0` after whatever function you are performing with it? Please clarify your query. And are you sure that you dont want to include second `if` in your loop? Cos in your current code its not included. And  the loop isn't making sense. Maybe if you could specify what you are trying to accomplish and the problem, you may get better help.

Comment: If you want act to stay at 0 then what's the point of incrementing it?

Comment: you forgot open { bracket for for loop and closing bracket } hence i is out of scope

Comment: I am not giving a specific code right here, but an example one. The point is to count several values for one key in a HashMap (in my case) and then to move to the next key and count again so that I have for every key overall integer value.

Comment: How does your hashmap look like?

Comment: <String, Hashmap<String, Integer > >
String e.g - UK ; America ; Africa , etc.
String e.g - black , white, asian 
Integer e.g- 2008 , 103432 , 2391      // for every country the values are diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but, here is an example that calculates values for a key in hashmap. Let's assume we have

```
US -> [X -> 55, Y -> 5 , Z -> 10, ...] as one object
UK -> [X -> 99, Y -> 1, Z -> 50, W-> 23, ...] as other object
```

Where X, Y and Z are of type String and their values are of type Integer. The following code, stores the above structure and then calculate X,Y,Z for US and UK.

```
 //structure to store a map of key/value for a key
 Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>(); 

   //key/value map
   Map<String, Integer> US = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
   US.put("X", 1200); 
   US.put("Y", 50); 
   US.put("Z", 25552); 
   //can add any number, doesn't have to be three

   Map<String, Integer> UK = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
   UK.put("X", 222); 
   UK.put("Y", 52); 
   UK.put("Z", 18);

   hashmap.put("USA", US); 
   hashmap.put("UK", UK);

   //loop through main keys (i.e. US, UK, Africa, etc.)         
   for (String key : hashmap.keySet()) {
       Map<String, Integer> temp = hashmap.get(key); 
        System.out.println("Calculating for " + key);
        Integer sum = 0; 
        //for each key i.e. UK loop through its properties
        for(String otherKey: temp.keySet()) {
            sum = sum + temp.get(otherKey); 
        }
      System.out.println("Sum for " + key + " is " + sum);
   }
```

the output:

```
Calculating for USA
Sum for USA is 26802
Calculating for UK
Sum for UK is 292
```

Comment: I know that my question is a bit unclear as I don't have a clue about that iteration and calculation overall. You did a great job, straightforward answer ! Thanks a lot!